# keyListener with DigitsKeyListener and inputType not working together as programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-edittext

I need to change the input type for Edittext when change the tab.

- For 1st: Number
- For 2nd: Text (Only few character allowed with Number)

When going to set this ontabChangeListener, can show the keyboard with text but digits which has been set that is not working.

Ex:

```
if (tabPosition == 0) {
    editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
} else {
    editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
    editText.keyListener = DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789Aa")
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why not add some code?  Did use setInputType?

Comment: @Anna Edited content with some code.